# Curly brackets after Update statement in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
Update {0} Set
    ZENKURI_KINGAKU = :ZENKURI_KINGAKU,
    D_SYUKEI_ZANDAKA_KINGAKU = :D_SYUKEI_ZANDAKA_KINGAKU,
    UPD_DATE = :UPD_DATE,
    UPD_USER = :UPD_USER,
    UPD_PRG = :UPD_PRG
Where
    SIR_CD = :SIR_CD And    
    SYR_YM = :SYR_YM
```

This is an Oracle Sql and I'm trying to convert it to Mysql but I have no idea what does this `{0}` mean. It took me an hour to researching.Any help or ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a table name placeholder. probably the related application replaces it with a table name. I don't think this is a general oracle syntax. (Maybe I am wrong, but afaik it is only possible to bind constant values, not field names, nor table names.)